# Redact sensitive information when using ServiceStack.Text to serialize to log files

Tags: servicestack, nlog, servicestack-text, redaction

I am using `ServiceStack.Text` and `ServiceStack.Logging.NLog` to log the DTO requests sent to/from a web service from a .NET client application.  While the machines are generally secure, I'd like to redact sensitive information that might be stored in plain-text (think name, address, basic auth creds, etc.).

I've looked at the various `JsConfig<T>` methods, but it seems like I'd have to implement a `SerializeFn<T>` for every DTO.  There is risk in "missing one", and I'd want to apply it only to the scope of logging.

I've looked at `NLog` filters, and `when` just changes whether the message is logged.

Is there some universal way to replace sensitive properties/keys/attributes with a redaction marker when logging DTOs with `ServiceStack.Logging` \ `NLog`?

Answer (score 0):

There's no scoped serializer options that changes what fields should be serialized.

Possible solutions I'd be looking at would be maintaining a whitelist of DTO Types with sensitive info that should not be logged or using reflection to set properties you don't want to `null`.

ServiceStack has APIs for [converting Types in an object dictionary](http://docs.servicestack.net/auto-mapping#populating-types-from-an-object-dictionary) and rehydrate types from Dictionaries so you could do something like:

```
var map = requestDto.ToObjectDictionary();
ProtectedNames.ForEach(x => map.Remove(x));
```

You can then either serialize the remaining properties in `map` or convert it back into the Request DTO without the removed properties:

```
var safeDto = map.FromObjectDictionary(requestDto.GetType());
```